# BoxShadow to Container child of SizeTransition Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a stretch nabar, when I click on the "autres" icon, there's a transition like the screen below.

I'm trying to put a BoxShadow to a Container which is child of a SizeTransition.

I made this code:

Here's the sandbox: https://flutlab.io/editor/1c7de2dd-edc4-4e09-b1b3-4a4d63f1a162

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
///Here's the part i talk about
        SizeTransition(
          sizeFactor: _animation,
          axisAlignment: -1,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: ColorResources.white,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0).withOpacity(0.5),
                  spreadRadius: 2,
                  blurRadius: 7,
                  offset: Offset(0, 3),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: const SizedBox(
                    height: kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.menu_outlined),
                        const SizedBox(height: 0.0),
                        Text(
                          "Menu",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0).withOpacity(0.5),
                spreadRadius: 5,
                blurRadius: 7,
                offset: const Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            backgroundColor: ColorResources.white,
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            fixedColor: ColorResources.blue,
            onTap: _onItemTapped,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu_outlined),
                label: "Fil d'actu",
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                label: 'Idées',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.output),
                label: 'Entraide',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_option_key_outlined),
                label: 'Projets',
              ),
              const BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu_outlined),
                label: 'Autres',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

For the moment, the only result that I have is like this:

[image: Result]

How can I add the same Shadow as the navbar?

Comment: you can try wrapping with `Material(elevation:`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @YeasinSheikh , by the way, it does not work

Comment: Can you remove other dependency and make it with simple widget like Icon instead of image, so that others can copy the question snippet and reproduce the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the shadow is not appearing on the `SizeTransition` widget is that it does not have a size until it is animated, so the shadow is not visible. One solution is to wrap the `SizeTransition` widget with a `Container`, which will allow the shadow to be visible.

We also add height to the `SizedBox` to `kBottomNavigationBarHeight` (you can set your own height, instead)

Here's the updated code snippet:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0).withOpacity(0.5),
        spreadRadius: 5,
        blurRadius: 7,
        offset: const Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
      ),
    ],
  ),
  child: SizeTransition(
    sizeFactor: _animation,
    axisAlignment: -1,
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {},
            child: SizedBox(
              height: kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.menu_outlined),
                  const SizedBox(height: 0.0),
                  Text(
                    "Menu",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ))
```

This should create a fixed height container for the `SizeTransition` widget, allowing the shadow to be visible.

Result:
[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for you reply. I tried and there's no result..

Comment: Can you modify the original question and remove any external dependencies, so that I can copy/paste the code and attempt to test on my end?

Comment: Hello @Riten , i did it !

Comment: @MICHELBaptiste just edited again to make it cleaner. Hope this helps!